# Detect button click with javascript using parent class and no ID

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to simply detect the click of an html  tag. It only works if the button has an ID, but my button has no id or class.

html

```
<div class="parent">
     <button>Submit</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementByClassName('.parent button').onclick = function() {
      alert("clicked");
    };
```

Comment: `getElementByClassName` does not work like that. It would need to have `getElementByClassName` with the class and than another look up with `getElementsByTagName` or just use modern `querySelector` to get the element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this, `document.querySelector` works just like css selectors.

```
document.querySelector('.parent button').onclick = function() {
  alert("clicked");
};
```

Comment: What if the button is in an iframe? This doesnt seem to work when the button is in an iframe. I keep getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Comment: I wrapped in this and it works to detect when button is in iframe!  window.onload=function(){ }

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.querySelector()` with `addEventListener` :

```
document.querySelector('.parent button').addEventListener('click', function() 
{ 
     alert("clicked"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="parent">
     <button>Submit</button>
</div>

document.querySelector('.parent > button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Clicked!');
});
```

Comment: This actually fires an alert when you click on the <div> with a class of parent -- not when you press the button. It's kind of a semantic issue, but it matters

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that : )

Answer (score 0):

you are using `getElementByClassName` and giving it a Css Selector string.
therefore it returns null, as there is no element with class ".parent button"

Use `querySelector` instead,

```
document.querySelector('.parent button').onclick = function() {
  alert("clicked");
};
```